# Configuring Kafka-zookeeper cluster in Prometheus Discovery(Using Strimzi Kafka cluster)

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, prometheus, strimzi

I have a running Kafka-zookeeper cluster using Strimzi cluster-operator.
I have followed the KB http://strimzi.io/docs/master/ for this. The metrics for kafka and zookeeper are available from the port 9404. I have to configure this cluster setup to Prometheus for monitoring. The Strimzi itself has a KB for configuring Prometheus too(http://strimzi.io/docs/master/#assembly-metrics-deployment-configuration-kafka). But my issue is, I can't configure the cluster according to their KB, Because in my Prometheus setup I have to configure service-monitor for discovering the applications,and I need to specify the metrics available port in its service. But I could not found any solution for this. Requesting help...

Answer (score 0):

the current implementation already sets the Prometheus annotations on the Kafka and Zookeeper services (they are named `my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap` and `my-cluster-zookeeper-client`).
These annotations are:

prometheus.io/path   /metrics
prometheus.io/port   9404
prometheus.io/scrape     true

But for having them, you need to enable metrics. It's possible by setting the `metrics` field in the `Kafka` resource for Kafka and Zookeeper cluster. You can find more info here: http://strimzi.io/docs/master/#assembly-metrics-deployment-configuration-kafka.

Furthermore, the repo provides you an example of Kafka cluster with metrics enabled. It's here: https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/blob/master/metrics/examples/kafka/kafka-metrics.yaml.